# Interfacing GPIB with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, instrumentation, gpib

I was wondering if it is possible to interface with GPIB Instruments by using C++ and Qt. If it is possible, can anyone tell me how easy it would be and/or point me in a direction for a tutorial or examples?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible. Part of the package should be a 488.2 API for C programs, which you can also use from a C++ and/or Qt program. You may have to wrap the header file in extern "C", if there is no such line in the header file.